# Oction-vue in nuxt: unexpected identifier

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, octicons

I would like to use the icons from Octicon, my project is written in nuxt.js, so I decided to use [this](https://github.com/Justineo/vue-octicon) Octicon Component for Vue.js. 
I created a file called octicon.js and added it to /plugins and registered it in nuxt.config.js. When I start my app, I get the message "unexpected identifier".

`/plugins/octicion.js` :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import octicon from 'vue-octicon/components/Octicon.vue'

// Pick one way betweem the 2 following ways

// only import the icons you use to reduce bundle size
import 'vue-octicon/icons/repo'

// or import all icons if you don't care about bundle size
import 'vue-octicon/icons'

Vue.use(octicon);
```

In `MyComponent.vue` I use it like

```
<template>
   <div>
      <octicon name="repo-forked" label="Forked Repository"></octicon>
   </div>
</template>
```

`nuxt.config.js` looks like

```
   plugins: [
        "@/plugins/bootstrap-vue",
        "@/plugins/octicon.js"
    ],
```

My Browser shows me:

[image: Error]

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you probably need to do. The plugin is only required on the client side so you should specify this in nuxt.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    "@/plugins/bootstrap-vue",
    { src: '~/plugins/octicon.js', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

Secondly you may need to add it to the transpile build option, also in nuxt config.js:

```
build: {
    transpile: ['octicon.js']
  }
```

You may also want to wrap the `<octicon>` tag in a `<no-ssr>` tag.